# Is it possible to have a 2 handed bow with a shield?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-demon-hunter

I am a demon hunter and I want to have a 2 handed bow with a shield. It seems like it should be possible since a shield is "off-hand." Is there any shield, bow combination that allows this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**No, it's not possible.**

The following combinations will work:

2h Bow + Quiver
2h Crossbow + Quiver
1h Hand crossbow + 1h Hand crossbow
1h Hand crossbow + Shield
1h Hand crossbow + Quiver

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible to have a shield and 2 handed bow or crossbow, The only offhand you can use with a 2 handed bow is a quiver. If you would like to use a shield you would have to use a hand crossbow.